# How to fix unable to find template on generate:bundle with Symfony?

Tags: symfony

I can't generate a bundle with app/console shell.

I have this error each time I run the command: generate:bundle

```
[Twig_Error_Loader]                                                                                                                                         
Unable to find template "bundle/home.html.twig.twig" (looked into: /home/lan/Documents/nighteyes/vendor/sensio/generator-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/GeneratorBun  
dle/Command/../Resources/skeleton, /home/lan/Documents/nighteyes/vendor/sensio/generator-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/GeneratorBundle/Command/../Resources).
```

It fails after "Do you confirm generation".

How can I do to fix it?